# Adding together values from multiple spreadsheets (VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In my Excel workbook, I have three separate spreadsheets. The spreadsheets are identical in format and represent count values for different categories (passenger cars, trucks, etc.). I need to combine the spreadsheets in the following way and create a new workbook with the combined data (CombinedCount.xlsx):

> ='Passenger'!B3+'Heavy Truck'!B3+'Light Truck'!B3

There are a lot of cells to add together, and this code will be applied to a large number of workbooks with the exact same format. Is there a way to automate this process with some Python code?

Comment: There are [plenty of existing Python modules](http://www.python-excel.org/) that can work directly with XLS and XLSX files, as well as a [newer module called `OpenPyXL`](https://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/).

Answer (score 0):

Is there some particular reason why you want to do this with Python? 
Excel can do most of this by itself, with this VBA macro:

```
Sub CombineSheets()
'
' Add three identically-formatted sheets,
' putting the result into a fourth one, and then moving it to a new workbook.
'

    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(3)
    Sheets(4).Name = "Combined Counts"
    Sheets(2).Select
    Cells.Copy
    Sheets(4).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Operation:=xlAdd
    Sheets(3).Select
    Cells.Copy
    Sheets(4).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Operation:=xlAdd
    Sheets(4).Move
End Sub
```

This

- Makes a complete copy of the first sheet, placing it after the third sheet. 
  The new sheet can be subsequently referenced as `Sheets(4)`. 
  If the first sheet is called `Passenger`,
  then the new sheet will initially be called `Passenger (2)`.
- Rename the new sheet `Combined Counts`.
- Copy all of the second sheet, and paste it onto the new sheet using addition. 
  (This is the function that you can access interactively with “Paste” → “Paste Special…”
  and then selecting “Add” from the “Operation” section.) 
  And then repeat with the third sheet. 
  Non-numeric data (i.e., text) on the second and third sheets is ignored. 
  If the first sheet has text in a given cell, that text will persist to the result,
  even if one of the other sheets has a number there. 
  (But this shouldn’t be an issue, since you say the sheets are identical in format.)
- Separate the new worksheet from the book, creating a new workbook.

You can then save the new workbook and close its window by putting something like

```
    Do
        fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
                            FileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    Loop Until fName <> False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName
    ActiveWindow.Close
```

before the `End Sub`. 
Or you could obtain the filename some other way.

Comment: Thanks for this code--I will try it and get back to you.  My task is to write a code that can be applied to a large number of excel files containing similar data (specifically, vehicle count data for all intersections within my region).  I've never worked with Excel VBA before and am wondering if this code can only be applied to one workbook at a time.  I have a sample group of data files containing six workbooks (3 sheets per workbook), but the actual data will probably have hundreds.  Finding an automated way to organize these files will be an important step in future analysis...

Comment: Also, I tried the code and the output sheet was only a copy of Sheet1 (Passenger).  The sheets were not added together properly.  How should I fix this?

Comment: The Error code: 400

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this task.  It can import all or selected files from a Folder and build a table combining data from each file (assuming they have a standard layout as you have indicated).  For example:

http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2013/11/26/from-txt-files-to-bi-solution/

Power Query also has a Group By function which can summarize data and aggregate it e.g. Count, Count Distinct, Sum, Average etc.